# How to filter rows with null values in any of its columns in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I want to filter out the output without rows containing null values or blank columns. I am using SQL Server 2012 there is no option named **'Blank'** as in SS2005 where I can filter the rows. I also tried following expression but it gives me error or not showing correct output

```
=IsNothing(Fields!ABC.Value)!= True 
=Fields!ABC.Value = ''
```

Please suggest the solution.

Comment: If you apply filter via dataset or tablix properties (Filters tab) your condition may look like Expression - Fields!ABC.Value, operator <>, Value =Nothing

Answer (score 37, accepted):

We should use the isNothing method in the Expression, change the Text to Boolean
and then Value will be "True"

for example:

```
Expression 
=IsNothing(Fields!TestA.Value)<>True
(Expression type should be Boolean)
Operator
=
Value
=True
```

Comment: Within the Filter dialogue, in the Value field, if you use ="True" then that is a string and will cause an error because it cannot be compared to your Boolean expression. You just need to use the constant TRUE and write that directly into the value field.

Comment: @Aasai Say for example I'm looking at the text field in the Expression dialog box for setting the expression....what part of all that should I type there?

Answer (score 59):

- Pull up the tablix or group properties
- Switch to "Filters"
- Add a new filter
- Set the expression to:

  `=IsNothing(Fields!YourFieldHere.Value)`
- **Set the type to "Boolean"** (see screenshot below) otherwise you'll get a "cannot compare data of types boolean and string" error.
- Set the value to `false`

[image: screenshot of grouping dialog, higlighting expression type setting]

This works for filtering both rows and groups.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm getting `The FilterValue expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ has the value “False”, which is not a valid Boolean value`

Comment: I might be a little too late. Have you changed the type from text to Boolean as in the screenshot above from @Tim Abell.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the SQL query, so that it will not return NULL values in the column to group on, but let it return a dummy value; for example: ISNULL(columnA, 'dummy')

In the column group definition add a filter: ColumnA <> 'dummy'.